# Python: got an output image with unexpected grid lines

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am writing a function that scales the input image into times of
its input size. The function Resize(Mat I, float s) first fills in the and Mat’s
that contained the query point coordinates. Then I calculate the query value by
using bilinear interpolation.

The output image seems to be alright except it has an unexpected # shape grid on it. Can you provide any hint for the resolution?

Output image:
[image]

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Mat I, float s
def Resize(I, s):
    orig_x = I.shape[0];
    orig_y = I.shape[1];

    tar_x = int (orig_x * s) #int tar_x and tar_y
    tar_y = int (orig_y * s);

    #print(tar_x)
    
    # Query points
    X = np.empty((tar_y, tar_x), np.float32)
    Y = np.empty((tar_y, tar_x), np.float32)

    # calc interval between output points
    interval = (orig_x-1) / (tar_x-1)
    
    # Setting the query points
    for i in range(0, tar_y):
        for j in range(0, tar_x):
            #set X[i, j] and Y[i,j]
            X[i][j] = j * interval
            Y[i][j] = i * interval

    
    # Output image
    output = np.empty((tar_y, tar_x), np.uint8)

    # Performing the interpolation
    for i in range(0, tar_y):
        for j in range(0, tar_x):
            #set output[i,j] using X[i, j] and Y[i,j]
            
            x = X[i][j]
            y = Y[i][j]
            x1 = math.floor(x)
            x2 = math.ceil(x)
            y1 = math.floor(y)
            y2 = math.ceil(y)
            vq1= (x-x1)*I[y1,x2] + (x2-x)*I[y1,x1]
            vq2= (x-x1)*I[y2,x2] + (x2-x)*I[y2,x1]
            output[i,j] = (y-y1)*vq2 + (y2-y)*vq1
            

    return output

s= 640 / 256

I = cv.imread("aerial_256.png", cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

output = Resize(I,s)

output = cv.cvtColor(output, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.imshow(output)
plt.savefig("aerial_640.png",bbox_inches='tight',transparent=True, pad_inches=0)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Since every imaging library ever written has a working interpolated resize function, why would you try to write this yourself?

Comment: @TimRoberts Doesn't matter why OP is writing this themselves. It could be for educational purposes or whatever other valid reason. OP has a scoped question that requires a defined answer. Unfortunately, OP didn't offered the original image, that would make debugging the code a little bit easier. I'm suspicious of the `floor` and `ceil` functions. Maybe they are truncating the coordinates of some pixels, or maybe your sampling interval is buggy. OP, debugging by steps, pixel by pixel, should give you a clear insight of the problem.

Comment: _can't computationally afford the implementation of an external imaging library_ -- Perhaps you did not notice that he is already importing opencv, numpy, and matplotlib.

Comment: `output = cv.resize( I, 640, 480 )`  does bilinear interpolation by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a black pixel where `x` is an integer and where `y` is an integer.

Take a look at the following code:

```
x1 = math.floor(x)
x2 = math.ceil(x)
vq1= (x-x1)*I[y1,x2] + (x2-x)*I[y1,x1]
vq2= (x-x1)*I[y2,x2] + (x2-x)*I[y2,x1]
```

Assume: `x = 85.0`

`x1 = floor(x)` = `85`
`x2 = ceil(x)` = `85`
`(x-x1)` = `(85-85)` = `0`
`(x2-x)` = `(85-85)` = `0`

`vq1 = (x-x1)*I[y1,x2] + (x2-x)*I[y1,x1]` = `0*I[y1,x2] + 0*I[y1,x1]` = `0`
`vq2 = (x-x1)*I[y2,x2] + (x2-x)*I[y2,x1]` = `0*I[y2,x2] + 0*I[y2,x1]` = `0`

`output[i,j] = (y-y1)*vq2 + (y2-y)*vq1` = `(y-y1)*0 + (y2-y)*0` = `0`

Result:
In the entire column where `x = 85.0` the value of `output[i,j]` is zero (we are getting a black column).

Same result applied to `y = 85.0` - we are getting a black row.

---

When does `x` value is an integer?

Take a look at the following code:

```
# calc interval between output points
interval = (orig_x-1) / (tar_x-1)

# Setting the query points
for i in range(0, tar_y):
    for j in range(0, tar_x):
        #set X[i, j] and Y[i,j]
        X[i][j] = j * interval
```

`interval = (orig_x-1) / (tar_x-1) = 255/639` = `(3*5*17/(3*3*71)` = `85/213`
`j * interval` = `j * 85/213`
Each time `j` is a multiple of `213`, `j * interval` is an integer (we are getting a black column).
It happens when `j=0`, `j=213`, `j=426`, `j=639`, so there are two black columns (beside margins).
There are also two visible black rows (beside margins).

---

Suggested solution:
Replace `x2 = math.ceil(x)` with `x2 = min(x1 + 1, orig_x-1)`.
Replace `y2 = math.ceil(y)` with `y2 = min(y1 + 1, orig_y-1)`.

Corrected loop:

```
for i in range(0, tar_y):
    for j in range(0, tar_x):
        #set output[i,j] using X[i, j] and Y[i,j]           
        x = X[i][j]
        y = Y[i][j]
        x1 = math.floor(x)
        x2 = min(x1 + 1, orig_x-1)
        y1 = math.floor(y)
        y2 = min(y1 + 1, orig_y-1)
        vq1= (x-x1)*I[y1,x2] + (x2-x)*I[y1,x1]
        vq2= (x-x1)*I[y2,x2] + (x2-x)*I[y2,x1]
        output[i,j] = (y-y1)*vq2 + (y2-y)*vq1
```

---

Result:
[image]